# Control of External Power Source with Arduino

Tags: arduino, fet

Please pardon my ignorance, I'm still trying to wrap my head around this problem. I have built a circuit that will allow me to control distribution of voltage from a single external power supply to one or more of four test units using the pins of an Arduino to control the switching. The circuit looks like this:

[image: External Power Supply Control Circuit]

The power supply positive and negative are connected at J1 and J2 with the units being attached at J3-J10. S1 and S2 are used for interacting with the user and are not relevant this question. The Arduino is a MICRO that is being powered by a wall wart that provides 5V and 2A.

I find that when the circuit is sitting idle, none of the Arduino pins attached to the transistors are LOW (the LOW state at the transistor allows voltage to flow at the FET), but the power supply attached is on, I see a slowly building voltage at any of the output pairs (J3 and J4, etc.).

I did not see this when the circuit was in the breadboard and I've triple checked and resoldered many of my connections to be sure everything is hooked up correctly. I'm sure that I'm missing a very simple answer to my question, but it alludes me. Any help or clarification would be most helpful. Feel free to ask for any other information you might need.

Comment: Your negative supply voltage appears to be connected directly to ground and all the sources of your FETs. Meanwhile all the gates are connected to 5V. If this works at switching at all, I think it's safe to say your arduino is being abused.

Comment: I'm pretty confident your schematic is wrong, though, if the circuit works anything like you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Your schematic seems to be wrong. With all gates of the FETs directly attached to 5V, you will never be able to control the gate voltage in order to switch the FETs.

Comment: As I read the diagram it is correct when compared to the physical circuit. And it does work other than this problem I'm writing about here... Though your point makes me think that could be pointing to my problem. Time to experiment.